# use of final keyword in android

Tags: java, final

One activity calls this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(DrinkCategoryActivity.this, DrinkActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(DrinkActivity.EXTRA_DRINKNO, (int) id);
```

and then in another activity, the one that receives the intent, is the following code

```
public class DrinkActivity extends Activity {
    public static final String EXTRA_DRINKNO = "drinkNo";       // ???????

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_drink);

       // Get the drink from the intent
       int drinkNo = (Integer)getIntent().getExtras().get(EXTRA_DRINKNO);   // ?????
       Drink drink = Drink.drinks[drinkNo];
```

The part I don't understand is the whole declaration and definition of the `EXTRA_DRINKNO` variable in the second activity. First, I was just expecting it to be defined as an `int` NOT as a `String`. What is the point of assigning it an actual value of `"drinkNo"`?

Then later (see the second question mark marked line) `drinkNo` is cast to an `Integer`. Is this even the same variable?

Comment: "drinkNo is cast to an integer" No it isn't (and what integer could it be cast to, anyway?). `Bundle.get` takes a String parameter, and for this key happens to return a value which can be cast to `Integer`..

Comment: This question has nothing to do with the `final` keyword - it would work exactly the same without it (assuming nobody nefariously changes the value of `EXTRA_DRINKNO`).

Comment: This `intent.putExtra(DrinkActivity.EXTRA_DRINKNO, (int) id);` is equivalent to `intent.putExtra("drinkNo", (int) id);` and `(Integer)getIntent().getExtras().get(EXTRA_DRINKNO);` is equivalent to `(Integer)getIntent().getExtras().get("drinkNo");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`EXTRA_DRINKNO` represents the key into the map, it's not the integer value.  Perhaps it would be better named `EXTRA_DRINKNO_KEY`.

`get(EXTRA_DRINKNO)` is extracting the integer from `getExtras()` using the string value as a key.

The variable `drinkNo` represents the actual integer value.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are talking about the `final` in  your

```
public static final String EXTRA_DRINKNO = "drinkNo";
```

That is just there to get a global access without been able to change that variable again because it is used as a KEY for your Extras which is going to go in to your intent.

You can use,

```
int drinkNo = getIntent().getIntExtra(DrinkActivity.EXTRA_DRINKNO, -1);
```

-1 will get assigned to drinkNo if you did not have this,

```
intent.putExtra(DrinkActivity.EXTRA_DRINKNO, (int) id);
```

I am not sue about the `(int) id` *cast*. It is probably redundant.